# React Native iOS App crashes

Tags: ios, react-native

I followed the "Getting Started" to build my first React Native App.

This is what I do:

```
npm install -g yarn react-native-cli

react-native init AwesomeProject
cd AwesomeProject
react-native run-ios
```

However, the app crashed after building successfully.

Then I open Xcode to run the app, but the app crashed again.

Here is the information:

```
2016-12-05 13:26:26.633 [info][tid:main][RCTBatchedBridge.m:73] Initializing <RCTBatchedBridge: 0x60800019f210> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x6080000b1460>, executor: RCTJSCExecutor)
2016-12-05 13:26:26.634 AwesomeProject[89471:10945233] *** Assertion failure in -[RCTBatchedBridge loadSource:onProgress:](), /Users/Leaf/Desktop/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTBatchedBridge.m:197
2016-12-05 13:26:26.663 AwesomeProject[89471:10945233] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'bundleURL must be non-nil when not implementing loadSourceForBridge'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010adcc34b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000109cda21e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010add0442 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x00000001098a6d79 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:] + 166
    4   AwesomeProject                      0x00000001093ef035 -[RCTBatchedBridge loadSource:onProgress:] + 997
    5   AwesomeProject                      0x00000001093ed1a3 -[RCTBatchedBridge start] + 883
    6   AwesomeProject                      0x000000010942d20c -[RCTBridge setUp] + 684
    7   AwesomeProject                      0x000000010942c263 -[RCTBridge initWithDelegate:bundleURL:moduleProvider:launchOptions:] + 387
    8   AwesomeProject                      0x000000010942c072 -[RCTBridge initWithBundleURL:moduleProvider:launchOptions:] + 146
    9   AwesomeProject                      0x000000010938d077 -[RCTRootView initWithBundleURL:moduleName:initialProperties:launchOptions:] + 183
    10  AwesomeProject                      0x0000000109376585 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 245
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010d33e0be -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 290
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010d33fa43 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4236
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010d345de9 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1731
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010d342f69 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    15  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000110867723 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
    16  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011086759c -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 189
    17  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000110867925 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ad71311 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ad5659c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ad55a86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ad55494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    22  UIKit                               0x000000010d3417e6 -[UIApplication _run] + 434
    23  UIKit                               0x000000010d347964 UIApplicationMain + 159
    24  AwesomeProject                      0x000000010937695f main + 111
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010ed1e68d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

The content of `AppDelegate.m`

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Facebook, Inc.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the BSD-style license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree. An additional grant
 * of patent rights can be found in the PATENTS file in the same directory.
 */

#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import "RCTBundleURLProvider.h"
#import "RCTRootView.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"AwesomeProject"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: Show code of `AppDelegate.m` file.

Comment: @NiravD I have added the `AppDelegate.m`

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that Shadowsocks is running in the global mode. 
The problem solved after I turned it off.